# How do I know whether I am importing tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started working with tensorflow cpu version, but then I installed tensorflow-gpu for faster processing, but I'm not sure which one is currently working. How can I confirm that the current version running is indeed tensorflow-gpu?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot tell directly from python whether you are importing tensorflow from a `tensorflow` (CPU-only) or a `tensorflow-gpu` package.

However, you can ask tensorflow about the devices it knows:

```
from tensorflow.python.client.device_lib import list_local_devices
print(list_local_devices())
```

If there is any device with a `device_type` of type `GPU`, then you are definitely importing from `tensorflow-gpu`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on P-Gns code above and making something more automatable is the following:

```
from tensorflow.python.client.device_lib import list_local_devices
ss = "\n".join([str(s) for s in list_local_devices()]
numGpus = ss.count("device:GPU")
print("There are {} GPUs present".format(numGpus))
```

It takes the list of local devices, converts their attributes to a big string, and counts the number of GPUs in there. So copying and pasting the above text into my python gives me:

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.client.device_lib import list_local_devices
>>> ss = "\n".join([str(s) for s in list_local_devices()])
2018-06-27 09:30:43.309703: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-06-27 09:30:43.309796: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:911] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-06-27 09:30:43.309836: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:917]      0
2018-06-27 09:30:43.309869: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:930] 0:   N
2018-06-27 09:30:43.310186: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 5185 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
>>> print(ss)
name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 4228992220605196898

name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 5436997632
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 6685330293620217138
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"

>>> numGpus = ss.count("device:GPU")
>>> print("There are {} GPUs present".format(numGpus))
There are 1 GPUs present
>>>
```